# Regular Expression to match text between # and only if # is not preceded by '

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I'm trying to find a regular expression that can help me find all matches inside a string when they're inside # and only if # are not preceded by an apostrophe "'".

Basically I need to bold the text just as here when we use double * to bold text **like this**, but the apostrophe should work as an escape character.

For example
#Hello my name is Noé# should look like **Hello my name is Noé**

#Hello this has an escape apostrophe '# so I'll match until here# should look like **Hello this has an escape apostrophe '# so I'll match until here**

Inside a long text there might or might not be several matches:
"Hello I'm a text #I'm bold#, and I need to know how to match my text that's inside two '#, and #I will not match either 'cause I got no end"

So i can print it like 
"Hello I'm a text **I'm bold**, and I need to know how to match my text that's inside two '#, and #I will not match either 'cause I got no end"

If thats not possible with a RegExp I could program a finite state machine, but I was hoping I was possible, thank you in advance God bless you!

Note: I will handle the escape characters later by now I just need to know how to mach this

```
/(?<!')#.*(?<!')#/gim
```

This was the only thing I could come up with, but honestly, I have no idea how negative look behind works :(, with this regexp it would match wrong. For example, if I type: 
"I'm a text #and I should be a match# and this should not #But this should as well# and I'm just some random extra text"

matches from the first # occurrence until the last one, like so:

"I'm a text ***#and I should be a match# and this should not #But this should as well#*** and I'm just some random extra text"

Comment: Could you please share what you have already tried and where the exact problem came up? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
(?<!')#(.*?)(?<!')#
```

Here you can see the regexp working with your examples: https://regex101.com/r/wnguiA/1

`(?<!')` is **Negative Lookbehind**, it tells the regex engine to temporarily step backwards in the string, to check if the text inside the lookbehind can be matched there. `(?<!a)b` matches a `b` that is not preceded by an `a`.

More easy is the `(.*?)` that matches any character (except for line terminators); adding `?` tells the capturing group to be *not-greedy* and stop at the first occourence of the succesive token.

Comment: Woooow, this worked perfectly, thanks, I'm gonna keep reading and studying thanks, you're the admin! yeah it worked with the flags gm well in my case cause its a multi-line string, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To prevent triggering the negatilve lookbehind at all the positions not asserting a `'` to the left, you can also first match `#` and do the assertion after it.

```
#(?<!'#)(.*?)#(?<!'#)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/onb1TQ/1)

Another option instead of using the non greedy `.*?` is to use a negated character class matching any char except `#`

Then when you encounter `#` only match it if there is `'` before it using a positive lookbehind.

```
#(?<!'#)([^#\n]*(?:#(?<='#)[^#\n]*)*)#(?<!'#)
```

- `#(?<!'#)` Match `#` not directly preceded by `'`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^#\n]*` Optionally match any char except `#` or a newline
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `#(?<='#)` Match `#` not directly preceded by `'`
    - `[^#\n]*` Match optional repetitions of any char except `#` or a newline
  - `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat it to match all occurrences
- `)` Close group 1
- `#(?<!'#)` Match `#` not directly preceded by `'`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fPCoNb/1)